# Dynamic Excel Sheets load into SQL using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, ssis

I'm trying to load multiple excel format files (.xlsx) into sql. I have set up my package as followed. My excel files name and sheet name will change daily

```
File name: PROD File Tracking 02-10.xlsx - Month and Day change daily
Sheet name: 2-10$ -- month and day change daily
```

**Package Structure**

```
For each Loop Container -> Data Flow Task -> Excel Source -> OLE DB Destination
```

**Variables Values**

1. FileName: `Z:\Users\darsftp\BDS\GBRTest\PROD File Tracking 02-10.xlsx`
2. FolderPath: `Z:\Users\darsftp\BDS\GBRTest`
3. ExtProperties: `"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"`

**Need Help**

To dynamically pick up file daily with a dynamic sheet name.

*I know how to pick up files with a dynamic file name but not with a dynamic sheet name. That's where I'm having the issue.*

Comment: Try this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444169/import-data-from-excel-using-ssis-without-knowing-sheet-name

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable `Sheetname` and Set it's property `Evaluate as expression` to `True` and use the following expression:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@[User::Filename],FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename],"PROD File Tracking", 1 ) + LEN("PROD File Tracking"),100),".xlsx","") + "$"
```

So if your `Filename` variable value its `Z:\Users\darsftp\BDS\GBRTest\PROD File Tracking 02-10.xlsx` so `Sheetname` variable value will be `02-10$` wich is the sheetname.

And in your **Excel Source** read the sheetname from variable `Sheetname`

*Side note: Excel sheetname always end with `$` sign (it doesn't appear in excel)*

Read more about variable and expressions in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4564/ssis-variable-and-expression-example--part-1/)

**EDIT 1**

You have to add an expression the the `Excel connection manager` connection string property:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ @[User::Filename] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";"
```

Set `DelayValidation` property of Data Flow task to True.

**Usefull Links**

- [SSIS with variable excel connection manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691456/ssis-with-variable-excel-connection-manager)
- [Dynamically assign filename to excel connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string)
- https://www.google.com.lb/amp/s/sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/dynamic-file-name-for-excel-connection-manager-ssis/amp/

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm getting this error when I try that: 
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
Error at BDSEntityErrorIndicator [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

Comment: @SyedJafri This error is not from the sheet name. It is fron the connectionstring expression you are using. You said `I know how to pick up files with a dynamic file name` so my answer was on how to set sheet name dynamically

Comment: @SyedJafri waiting for your reply :)