# SSIS tab name issue

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

please help SSIS

I have the following as sql query when using an excel connection

August being the tab name

```
select * from [August$A14:N14]
```

But i want it to open on a specific month only for example tab August  (the tab name will change per month when i run the package hence trying to use the variable)

and rows A14:N14

i have tried something like the following

```
declare @monthname as varchar(20)=  DATENAME(month,DATEADD(MONTH, 
DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+2, 0))    

select * from [@monthname$A14:N14]
```

but I cannot get it to work

any suggestions please

update: i have tried variable method below too - i get invalid bracketing error

```
select * from [@(User::vMonth)$A14:N14]
```

please help

Comment: Your sql statement needs to be an _expression_ https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-expression-task-vs-evaluating-variable-as-expression/

Comment: select * from [@[User::vMonth]$A14:N14]  i get error invalid bracketing...i did try [@(User::vMonth)$A14:N14] same error please help @nick.mcdermaid

Comment: Read and understand expressions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-ver16 you need to set your sheet name as an "expression" then you can put text in there that is evaluated.

Comment: Perhaps this will help. I haven't used SSIS for many years so it's hard to guide you step by step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563777/dynamic-excel-sheets-load-into-sql-using-ssis